# Google API - Static Maps

Tags: php, html, css, api

Frankly, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  This is my code, but for some reason, the map is outputting a blank iFrame with a source URL that if I click will send me to the proper map, so the URL is being input correctly, but it's not actually being displayed on my website.

```
<?php $addressStr ="516 East Liberty Street, Ann Arbor, MI 48104"; ?>
<iframe width="206" height="175" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="<?php echo "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={$addressStr}&zoom=15&size=204x173&markers=color:orange|{$addressStr}&sensor=true&output=embed"; ?>"></iframe>
```

Comment: If it's solved, write an answer and accept it. Answers do not go in questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an iframe. You need a standard `<img>` tag ?

Comment: Well I feel stupid.  Just needed to convert that iframe to img... Thanks! >.<